# C - Data Storage / Access

Tags: c, database, sorting, data-structures, structure

As a novice programmer I want to stick with C for a while...

I would like to know what the best way to store user input long term. I want to build an organized, accessible, sortable, and modifiable storage method.

I will appreciate advice that sends me down a rabbit hole of my own research and trial and error.

Comment: Database.  Use something that is freely available and already works..No other approach is rational.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look into DBMS's. These are systems designed specifically with the needs you stated in your question. SQL, NoSQL, and others of the type. With them, you can save your data and access it from other applications, the original application, and even (if you want to) from other computers.